# Unit test exception with database without breaking other test

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception

I have a problem when I tried to test my class with the database. I am not using hibernate so I cannot rollback database. When exception occurs the database operation stops the test for the exception passes but it fails other test I wrote. How can I prevent this?

```
@RunWith(SpringJunit4ClassRunne.class)
@ContextConfiguration("test.xml")
public class MachineDaoTest{

@Autowired
private DataSource ds;

@Before
public void setUp(){...}

@Test
public void testFindVersion(){
....
}

@Test
public void testException() {
try {
someMethod.getVersion("xxyyzz");
fail("Expected DB Exception");
} catch (Exception e) {
assertTrue(e instanceof DbException);
}
```

Now in xml file I have included two sql file. One create tables and set values and another one that drop tables and cause exception. Since the database was autowired how am I able to rollback or make both test pass?

In an actual java file to be tested ...

```
...
try{
result = someMethod.getVersion("x");
if(result==null) {
 throw new DBexception("result should return");
} catch (DBexception e) {
e.getMessage();
}
...
```

Comment: If you are testing the database then strictly speaking you are _not_ doing a unit test, you are doing an integration test.

Comment: not testing database using value from database

Comment: do you mean those kind of test is going to be handled differently?